# Find the table(column) that a FK links to? MySql

Tags: mysql

I am ok with mysql. when i use `desc tablename` i can see columns with MUL meaning it is a foreign key. Now my question is, how do i find out exactly what table and column that column is pointing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/key-column-usage-table.html) table.

```
select * 
from information_schema.key_column_usage 
where table_schema = YOUR_DB and table_name = YOUR_TABLE 
order by constraint_name, poisition_in_unique_constraint
```

The `table_schema`, `table_name`, and `column_name` are the ones which reference the foreign key table. The `referenced_table_schema`, `referenced_table_name` and `referenced_column_name` will contain the information about the referenced table.